# Automating 'keyboard Access' for accessibility testing

Tags: selenium, accessibility, section508

Using Selenium WebDriver in Java, I am trying to automate a functionality("Ensure that actionable elements are keyboard accessible") where I have to go through all the interactive elements (links, radio button, check box, buttons etc) in a webpage by pressing keyboard key 'TAB'. It's under accessibility testing. I'm trying to automate 'keyboard access' from the accessibility testing.

Please suggest me Selenium WebDriver script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the sendkeys method of the WebElement requires a WebElement to send it to which kind of negates the test in the first place. Using an actions object would probably work.So my script would be something along the lines of

`static void goThroughTabs(){
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        int NumberOfElements = 10; //This is the number of elements to test
        for(int Counter = 0; Counter < NumberOfElements; Counter++){
            action.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();
        }
    }`

The bigger problem would be to make sure that it tabbed over every Element but for a problem like this I'd need more information regarding the specifics of the test.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much. The code you send me is working fine. Only problem is size of the elements. It's tabbing only 10 elements. 

int NumberOfElements = 10; //This is the number of elements to test.....

I need all the interactive elements(links, check box, radio button etc) in an array...Can anyone help me on that????????

Comment: The easiest way would be to let it collect all present elements by changing the line to int NumberOfElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("div")).size() + driver.findElements(By.tagName("button ")).size() /* +... */ ; and add a term for every kind kind of tag your elements are in (just use firebug). It will probably be a bigger Number than your actual amount of elements but given the fact that tabbing is cyclic it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to do it. You can use sendkeys() method passing KEYS.TAB and other Keys options available. Also, you can create an object of Robot class and pass the keyboard options.